# vb.net how do i add a new rows (and update) from datagridview programmatically to sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

asking a new question with regards to my previous problem.

so this is how it goes,
so far i was able make the following code to work (thanks to @JADE for helping me out, (a lot ) :)

```
Dim connstr As String = "server=midtelephone\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"

    cmdconn = New SqlConnection
    cmd = New SqlCommand        
    cmdconn.ConnectionString = connstr 
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn
    cmdconn.Open()

    Dim period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1


        With Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i)

            If IsDBNull(.Cells(0).Value()) OrElse .Cells(0).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(0).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                period = ""
            Else
                period = .Cells(0).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(1).Value()) OrElse .Cells(1).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(1).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                VOUCH_AMT = "0"
            Else
                VOUCH_AMT = .Cells(1).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(2).Value()) OrElse .Cells(2).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(2).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                INDIVIDUAL_AMT = "0"
            Else
                INDIVIDUAL_AMT = .Cells(2).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(3).Value()) OrElse .Cells(3).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(3).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                check_no = ""
            Else
                check_no = .Cells(3).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(4).Value()) OrElse .Cells(4).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(4).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                D_MAILED = ""
            Else
                D_MAILED = .Cells(4).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(5).Value()) OrElse .Cells(5).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(5).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                DIR_NO = ""
            Else
                DIR_NO = .Cells(5).Value()
            End If


        End With

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no)values" & _
            "('" & period.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & VOUCH_AMT & "," & INDIVIDUAL_AMT & ",'" & check_no.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & D_MAILED.Replace("'", "''") & "', '" & DIR_NO.Replace("'", "''") & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Saved")
    Next
    cmdconn.Close()

End Sub
```

now the problem is if i want to add new rows programmatically (i already set the dgv to edit programmatically ). what are the metrics or the next procedures to do? i have an edit button which enables the datagridview to be edited, something like this:

```
Private Sub btnEditmain_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEditmain.Click

    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
    btnSave.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

( also, as i check the table in my database, it seems that there's no changes made after clicking the save button ) pls. help me. thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the DataGridView to ListView and enable editing on ListView ?
The insert,edit and delete buttons will appear on the ListView if you have specified their commands respectively.

Comment: actually no. cuz what i wanna do is to make changes within the dgv rows and click save. so it can be updated automatically to the database, the code above seems to be working normally but when i tried to look in my database there's no changes made from the database, the fact that i already inserted a value from dgv ( no adding rows included, just editing the current rows )

Comment: Listview is your answer ! Try it on a testing page

Comment: i get what u are trying to point out, but the thing is, i already incorporated the given datagridview from different sql queries like

Comment: Well anyways. my codes above are datagridview based.. could you pls modify the codes above into list view ? pls so i could try it in my forms.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same but after long research this was the best. Load the table code then add a button once they edit the DataGridView.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.YourTable)
    Me.TableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet.YourTable)
    DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
    adap.Fill(dt)
    BindingSource.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        adap.Update(dt)
        ' adap.UpdateCommand(dt)
        ' MessageBox.Show("Saved successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        '  MessageBox.Show("Error updating database")
    End Try
```